# Alt+Click didn't work on Opera (current Opera 44)

Tags: javascript, opera

I try to use Alt+Click on Opera, but that's seem didn't work for me. It works well on Chrome, Firefox (IE, Edge, Safari - didn't check). Why Opera didn't detect Alt+Click for me.

My idea is: when Alt key is down - assign variable altpressed = true; if there are any keys event - up (include Alt key) - assign variable altpressed = false. If altpressed is true, I combine with click event to check. Code is very clear, has no another library (only JQuery).

```js
var altpressed = false;

$('body').keydown(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.altKey){
    altpressed = true;
    //$('#status').html('Alt is down');
  }
});
$('body').keyup(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  altpressed = false;
  //$('#status').html('Alt is up');
});
$('#hitarea').click(function(e){
  if(altpressed){
    $('#status').html('Alt + Click');
  }else{
    $('#status').html('Nothing!');
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id='hitarea' style='width:100px;height:100px;background-color:black;'></div>
<div id='status' style='color:red;'></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why aren't you testing for the `event.altKey` from inside your *click* handler? You don't need separate key event handlers for this.

Comment: Some browsers didn't support event as global!

Comment: I know. That's irrelevant to the point I was making.

Comment: Thanks :) You mean use e.altKey inside click handler. Yeah, it works on Opera! But I still don't understand, why that code didn't work? If I change altKey to ctrlKey, it work well on Opera!